# Apache Felix + Spring

Tags: spring, apache-felix

I have successfully created an osgi application with apache felix. Now I want to integrate spring 4 with it. How do I do it ? Can anyone provide me a complete example ?

Thanks
Arpan

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. What do want to use Spring for (now that it's a big project with dozens of features)? Do you want it for dependency injection? For OSGi service interaction? Or, something else?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Spring in your OSGi based java application for Spring Controllers or Dependency Injection you need to use [Apache Aries Blueprint](http://aries.apache.org/documentation/tutorials/blueprinthelloworldtutorial.html). [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/index.html) also provides a convenient distribution of the Felix OSGi Container with support for Apache Aries Blueprint. However before embarking on mixing Spring with OSGi I recommend reading the discussion on Blueprint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008786/osgi-blueprint-vs-spring-dm)